# problem with youama ajax login

Tags: ajax, login, magento-1.9, home

I just have installed the module ajax login and register from youama (url:http://www.youama.com/free-ajax-login-and-register-module-magento/). I followed the steps  about install. Somehow the module works fine on every page off my website, exept the homepage. does anyone have experience with this module or does anyone knows how i can fix this problem?
tnx!

Comment: This extension has ajax login .. https://magecomp.com/magento-mobile-login.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the same error message https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEITZ.png.

What happened was the extension added an additional jQuery.js file to the head **AFTER** my original jQuery.js file and **AFTER** I had declared jQuery.noConflict();

This caused the original jQuery file and the noConflict(); to be overwritten, causing this error.

You have a few options available to you to fix this problem.

1. Go into the Magento admin panel under System > Configuration > YOUAMA - Then uncheck change the jQuery pull-down to "No"
2. Remove any existing jQuery.js files and leave the Youama file to be added to the head. (Note: You may need to add jQuery.noConflict(); somewhere after the jQuery.js file)
3. Be sure the ajaxlogin.js file is being added to the head after your jQuery.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Install Firebug for Firefox or use Chrome Dev Tools with Google Chrome to diagnose this behavior - it's likely an issue with Javascript conflict on the home page.

You can also see the AJAX response otherwise.

P.S When I first read the subject, I read `problem with yo mama's ajax logic'` :-P

Comment: If you read 'yo mama' I think you need a break from the internet :).

Comment: I have checked and this is what i got:
![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LEITZ.png